# Laravel Eloquent Repository - Query giving unexpected result?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, repository-pattern

I'm using laravel eloquent queries to get the result of all students belonging to a department. 
The relationship is like this:
Each department has classes.
Each class has students.

If we are writing this on MySQL, we can have two versions:
Let's say we want students belonging to department 5.

1.

```sql
select * from class
   inner join student on class.id = student.class_id
   where class.department_id = 5;
```

Equivalent Laravel Eloquent Query:

```php
return $classRepo->where(['department_id'=>5])
            ->select(['id','department_id'])
            ->with(['students'])
            ->get();
```

2.

```sql
select * from student
   inner join class on class.id = student.class_id
   where class.department_id = 5;
```

Equivalent Laravel Eloquent Query:

```php
return $studentRepo
        ->with(['class' => function($query){
            $query->select(['id', 'department_id'])
                ->where(['department_id' => 5]);
        }])
        ->get();
```

Unexpectedly, the result from the first version is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "department_id" : 5,
        "students": [
            {
                "id": 61060,
                "name" : "Mark"
            },
            {
                "id": 61061,
                "name" : "Tony"
            }
           ]
    }
]
```

and from second version is this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 61057,
        "name" : "Smith",
        "class": null
    },
    {
        "id": 61058,
        "name" : "Jason",
        "class": null
    },
    {
        "id": 61060,
        "name" : "Mark",
        "class": {
            "id": 3,
            "department_id": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 61061,
        "name" : "Tony",
        "class": {
            "id": 3,
            "department_id": 5
        }
    }
]
```

Can anyone explain me the difference in the results between the two versions?
Why I am having nulls in the second version against the class key?
How laravel eloquent is actually processing the queries?

classRepo is an object of 'Classes' class

```
class Classes extends Model{

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\repoModels\Student','class_id','id');
    }

}
```

studentRepo is an object of 'Student' class

```
class Student extends Model{

   public function class()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\repoModels\Classes', 'id', 'class_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, im guessing those two results with "null" dont have relations, are you expecting them not to be present in the query?

Comment: Yeah, I'm expecting that those shouldn't come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correctly constrained.

Your eloquent query

```
return $studentRepo
        ->with(['class' => function($query){
            $query->select(['id', 'department_id'])
                ->where(['department_id' => 5]);
        }])
        ->get();
```

Is saying "Return all students with their corresponding class, BUT only give me the class if the class is in department 5".

What you want it to say is "Return all students with their corresponding class, BUT only give me students IF they are in a class in department 5".

The solution here is:

```
return $studentRepo
        ->with(['class' => function($query){
            $query->select(['id', 'department_id'])
                ->where(['department_id' => 5]);
        }])->whereHas('class', function($query) {
            $query->where('department_id', 5);
        })->get();
```

Please see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships under "Querying Relationship Existence"

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a left join, not an inner join.

If you start with students, eloquent will show all students with their corresponding class, even if it is null.

If you start with class, eloquent will show all classes and their corresponding students (ignoring the students without a class).

You probably have to ask eloquent specifically to do an inner join if you want both queries to return the same result.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same, but doesn't using **with** makes an inner join?